# Counterexample to Corollary of Banach-Steinhaus?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

This is the corollary under consideration, which I have proved:

> If $\left\{A_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of continuous,
>   linear maps from an $F$-space $X$ to a topological vector space $Y$,
>   and $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_nx=Ax$ exists for all $x\in X$, then $A$ is
>   linear and bounded.

How is this not a counterexample?

Define $A_n:c_0\to c_0$ by

$$\left(A_nx\right)_m=\begin{cases}
mx_m&m\leq n,\\
0&m>n,
\end{cases}$$

where $c_0$ is the space of all real sequences that converge to $0$. Then $x=\left(m^{-1/2}\right)_{m\in\mathbb N}\in c_0$ but $\left(Ax\right)_m=m^{1/2}\notin c_0$ since $\left\|Ax\right\|_\infty=\infty$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example doesn't satisfy the hypothesis that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_nx$ exists for all $x$.  Indeed, for your choice of $x=(m^{-1/2})$, $A_nx$ does not converge to any element of $c_0$.  (The sequences $A_nx$ converge pointwise to the sequence $(m^{1/2})$, but this sequence is not an element of $c_0$ and in any case it does not converge with respect to the sup norm.)

Comment: I know that this is a different question, but I suppose that if I change the codomain to $\mathbb R^\omega$, the hypothesis is still not satisfied since $\mathbb R^\omega$ is not a topological vector space?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is a topological vector space if you give it the product topology.  And your maps $A_n$ are in fact continuous for the product topology.  However, you reach no contradiction because your limit map $A$ is indeed linear and bounded, as the theorem says it should be.

Comment: Wouldn't it be unbounded for the same reason as in my last line in the OP?

Comment: The map $A:c_0\to\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is bounded because it is continuous (continuity is very easy to check with the product topology, you just have to check that each coordinate is continuous).  I don't know what the last line in the OP has to do with anything.